# AWS EMR machines not combining reduce output

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

I have a large job running in AWS's elastic map reduce cluster. By large, I mean over 800,000 files I'm processing with 25,000+ records per file. In my test runs I have been using 100 m1.medium spot instances for processing.

The job seemed to be running correctly, however I noticed that the outputs (part-00000, part-00001, etc.) have records with the same key listed in multiple outputs. Aren't these supposed to be reduced down in EMR?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that this key was the one getting out as the key in Mapper phase? DO you have any custom Partitioner or something ?

Comment: I do have a custom mapper which combines two fields for the key. What I've found with my digging is that each reduce task only combines the data it has, and doesn't care about working with the other reduce tasks.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't care about 'working with' other reduce tasks? Reduce tasks have never worked with other reduce tasks! Data is partitioned as per the output key from the mapper and all output for a single key has to go to the same reducer, unless there is some custom logic in the partitioner.

Comment: In the post-map sorting phase data wouldn't end up in the correct reduce task, resulting in each map task outputting records with the same key instead of having them combined into a single record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running into the same issue - I am using EMR to create an "inverted index" using the streaming API:

-input s3n://mybucket/html2 -output s3n://mybucket/results -mapper s3n://mybucket/mapper.py -reducer s3n://mybucket/reduce.py

Where //mybucket/html2 has a few html files and

mapper.py:

```
def main(args):
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        words = line.split()            
        for word in words:
            #do some preprocessing
            if word.startswith("http://"):
                #output the URL with a count of 1
                print "%s,%s" % (word, 1)
            else:           
                #cleanup HTML tags

                url = get_url() #irrelevant
                print "%s,%s" % (word, url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

and reduce.py is:

```
def main(args):
    current_word = None
    current_count = 0
    current_url_list = []
    key = None

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        (key, val) = line.split(',', 1)

        # If key is a URL - act as word count reducer
        if key.startswith("http:"):
            # convert count (currently a string) to int
            try:
                count = int(val)
            except:
                # count was not a number, so silently
                # ignore/discard this line
                continue

            # this IF-switch only works because Hadoop sorts map output
            # by key (here: word) before it is passed to the reducer
            if current_word == key:
                current_count += count
            else:
                if current_word:
                     #Check if previous word was a regular word
                    if current_word.startswith('http:'):
                        print '%s,%s' % (current_word, current_count)
                    else:
                        # previous word was a regular word
                        print '%s,%s' % (current_word, ','.join(current_url_list))
                current_count = count
                current_word = key
        else:
            #If key is a word - as act a URL-list-appending reducer
            if current_word == key:
                if val not in current_url_list:
                    current_url_list.append(val)
            else: #Got to a new key
                if current_word:
                    #Check if previous word was a URL
                    if(current_word.startswith("http:")):
                        print '%s,%s' % (current_word, current_count)
                    else:
                        # previous word was a regular word
                        print '%s,%s' % (current_word, ','.join(current_url_list))
                current_url_list = []
                current_url_list.append(val)
                current_word = key
```

I am starting this flow using the AWS console wizard ("Create new job flow") and except for setting the input, output, map and reduce scripts I am leaving everything as default (except for log path).

In the output I am getting few files and in them I see the same key (each time with different values).

Maybe this can help to shed more light on the issue and help resolve it

Comment: In my case the problem is with my mapper script - I am emitting the results from the map function with comma separator while Hadoop is expecting a tab separator.

Thus, key1,value1 and key1,value2 are both treated as different keys (with empty value) and not as a key-value pair and thus can possibly end up in a different reducer.

I fixed the issue by changing my mapper. 

It is also possible to add an option in the job flow creation to specify the separator:

-D stream.map.output.field.separator=,

Tomer

Comment: Interesting... I will have to try it with tabs and see if that does it. Thanks for the post!